# Folder Redirection on certain profiles is Labeled Wrong

Tags: windows, group-policy, folder-redirection

FTR I also suffer from "previous-admin-itis".

I had two client computers (Domain=SBS2003, Clients=Vista) that were using the improper folder for folder redirection.  Instead of pointing My Documents to `\\server\users\username\My Documents` these two users used `\\server\users\username` as the My Documents folder.  This is all the old guys' fault.

I've now upgraded the computers to Windows 7 and used Win7 Group policy to redirect the folders "correctly", which it does.  However, for the names of the folders, it still show "My Documents".  Observe pictures below:

> The users folder on the server, instead of showing their name, shows "My Documents".

[image: Users Dir]

> And in the folder, the location bar shows it named as "My Documents"...

[image: inside michelle pt.1]

> ...but the actual path has the user's name (michelle).

[image: inside michelle pt.2]

I know it's cosmetic, but I like uniformity.

Users are tied to client computers, they don't move around from machine to machine.  I'd prefer to NOT rebuild the profiles on the computers for these users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the affected profile directories for a hidden [`desktop.ini` file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144102%28VS.85%29.aspx).  This file can alter the display name and other directory display attributes.  Deleting the `desktop.ini` file should restore the directory's display to "normal".

On XP, the *PersonalizedName* in the *[CopyOnDelete]* section:

```
[DeleteOnCopy]
Owner=jscott
Personalized=5
PersonalizedName=My Documents
```

On Vista/7 the directory label can also be modified with *LocalizedResourceName* in *[.ShellClassInfo]*:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21798
```

The number -21798 refers to the *Downloads* directory.

We used File Server Resource Manager to create a File Screen to silently block `desktop.ini` files within user network profiles.

Comment: The file wasn't structured like that, but clearing the contents of the desktop.ini file did the trick!